# Did I get this right that with delegatecall the msg.sender is the last entity that calls delegatecall (example below)?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation

In other words:

If contract B is called by contract A:

B:

```
function externalcall() public
{
//msg.sender is contract A...
msg.sender.call.value(0);

}
```

Then assuming msg.sender.call above calls back contract A:

```
function () //we use fallback to catch anything here, say a call from B
{
address e = contract A
e.delegatecall... //here we call any function back in B, say 'setowner'
}
```

back to B:

```
function setowner(address _owner) public onlycontractoronlyowner
{
//check to see if the sender is the owner or the contract itself - as with dsauth, the famous library which uses both contract/owner...
}
```

So who will be the msg.sender at the very end? Will this be the user who started it all(A) or will this be the "innocent" contract B?

Also can this be done just with flow as described: using call.value or even better/worse: send/transfer? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry fallback seems like it should be set to payable...in any case this still doesn't change the original question...

Comment: It's hard to follow what you're saying since you don't have full code, but basically, delegatecall doesn't change msg.sender. If an EOA calls contract A, and contract A delegatecalls to contract B, and contract B delegatecalls to contract C, msg.sender will still read as the EOA address

Comment: ok in your scenario I guess since EOA calls A which contains delegatecall, correct? But in my case EOA = B and B calls A which then calls B which as delegatecall calling back A, in other words the function caller of delegatecall is A.

Comment: to elaborate a bit more: it seems as that while contract may  "call itself" via B which seems very dangerous...if my understanding is correct at all, it's not a major issue since delegatecall cannot alter storage of another contract, correct? That is, no contract without delegatecall can alter it's variables even if it's the msg.sender (as in my example).

Comment: consider this very perverted scenario which may be security issue: since A calls contract containing delegatecall and A is a "rich and innocent" contract, then B will end up back to say setowner in A but with new msg.sender: A...so A calls itself and has full authority to anything a contract is allowed to do. Again this isn't too devastating since B cannot specify which variable to be set in A it simply forwards value + msg.sender to any function in A. Again, I am speaking on the top of my head now, will have to look closer on this on ropsten later on so I may be wrong about many assumptions.

Comment: If I understand your first scenario, it's B calls A, A calls B, B delegatecalls A. In this scenario, msg.sender is A, and B is essentially executing the code of A *on B's storage*. This is your second point, that delegatecall doesn't alter the other contracts storage. It just executes the called contracts code on the callers storage.
Your second scenario is completely correct. A contract should never delegatecall into untrusted contracts, as it would be a blatant security risk, as A delegatecall B, and B could have some code that makes A do something malicious (selfdestruct for example)

Comment: Pretty much correct despite my confusing explanation,but yes...however my initial scenario still seems like a security issue. Since B will ultimately trigger A and A will check who the msg.sender is a function in A may be at risk, say like "function tradingenabled() { if msg.sender == address(this)... you can see where this is going. B will simply trigger A which has modifier checking who the msg.sender is and proceed, however B cannot send any values to A so something very devastating like "transfer" cannot occur or at best the contract will simply send it's own balance to the contract again.

Comment: again i simply assume that B "pings" back A to reassure the function exists which may be completely wrong...

Comment: I'm still confused about that scenario. It might help if you write some complete solidity code as an example. Yes, if A delegatecalls B, and B delegatecalls the function `function enableTrading(){require(msg.sender === address(this)...` on A, then yes. That is a security issue. That's why I said it is definitely a security hole to delegatecall into untrusted code, as it can make a contract do anything, even call it's own functions from itself